# Remove all H tags from one page in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.5

I need to remove all the H tags in my homepage and replace it with some other tags.
I tried in different ways using typoscript and nothing working.

Even the `content.defaultHeaderType` is also not working in my case.
All the content elements ate processed using FCE.

Am using TYPO3 4.5.29
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all headers from within content, plugins, rte and so on an easy way could be the extension [Ext:regex](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/regex). It an old extension but good at all and we used it even in a TYPO3 6.x project.

You can use it for your needs in this way:

```
config.regex {
    # replace opening tags
    pattern1 = /<h[1-6]>/
    pattern1.replacement = <othertag>

    # replace closing tags
    pattern2 = /<\/h[1-6]>/
    pattern2.replacement = </othertag>

    # shorter - replace both tags
    pattern3 = /<h[1-6]>(.*)<\/h[1-6]>/
    pattern3.replacement = <othertag>$1</othertag>
}
```

It's untested but it should work for your needs.